# Hardcode partial input value in a Rails form_for field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, form-for

I have a Rails form where the user is able to make a Top5 list. While they are able to label the list, all lists start with the phrase "Top 5 Greatest." Of course, it's easy to use Regex and append this phrase to the front of a list in the controller, but then I'm stuck doing it for both the create and update actions, so it's not very dry. Is there a way to hardcode a partial value in a rails form_for that will then be combined with the rest of the form input and sent to the controller?

This is currently what the form looks like (minus the form_for partial):

```
  <br><%= f.label "Top Five Greatest:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: user.id %>
  <br><%= f.label "#1" %>
  <%= f.text_field :number1 %>
  <br><%= f.label "#2" %>
  <%= f.text_field :number2 %>
  <br><%= f.label "#3" %>
  <%= f.text_field :number3 %>
```

I'd really appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override setter method:
`# put this in your model:`

```
def title=(value)
    super("Top 5 Greatest #{value}")
end
```

Comment: if i try to just add that in the text field it gives me an error:

Comment: undefined method `Top 5 Greatest' for #<List:0x00007ffab8ee1730>
Extracted source (around line #17):
15
16
17
18
19
20
              

  <br><%= f.label "Top Five Greatest:" %>
  <%= f.text_field "Top 5 Greatest".to_sym %><br>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: user.id %>
  <br><%= f.label "#1" %>
  <%= f.text_field :number1 %>

Comment: Oops... Do you want to DRY `f.text_field :number1` `f.text_field :number2` `f.text_field :number3`? I saw you use "Top 5 Greatest".to_sym

Comment: no, just the title so that the it was always send "Top 5 Greatest" and allow the user to choose the subject. So the user would just enter "Restaurants" and the controller would receive "Top 5 Greatest Restaurants" for the title field.

Comment: In this case I suggest an override setter approach. I've updated my answer you can check it